# Узнать цвет клетки на шахматной доске - проверьте решение

Tags: python, цвета, шахматы

Потратил на изучение Python уже около 70 часов. Посмотрите пожалуйста мини программку. При введении буквы и цифры - она должна вывести в ответ какого цвета клетка(рисунок прилагаю). Я понимаю что возможно код ужасен, но меня интересует - правильно ли все сделано логически и тд? Если можно сделать проще то как ? Или я вообще неправильно решил задачу. Спасибо...

[image: Шахматная доска]

```
letter=input('Please enter the letter-> ')
digit=int(input('Please enter the digit-> '))

letters_list=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
letters_list_black=['a','c','e','g']
letters_list_white=['b','d','f','h']
digits_list=range(1,9)
chess_desk_letter=[]
chess_desk_number=[]

for letter_checking in letters_list:
        if letter==letter_checking:
                chess_desk_letter.append(letter)
                break
else:
        print('Not in list, use A-H')
for digit_checking in digits_list:
        if digit==digit_checking:
                chess_desk_number.append(digit)
                break
else:
        print('Not in list use 1-8')
        
if chess_desk_letter[0] in letters_list_black:
        print(chess_desk_letter,chess_desk_number)
        color=(chess_desk_number[0]%2)
        if color==0:
                print('White')
        else:
                print('Black')
elif chess_desk_letter[0] in letters_list_white:
        print(chess_desk_letter,chess_desk_number)
        color=(chess_desk_number[0]%2)
        if color==0:
                print('Black')
        else:
                print('White')
```

Comment: "Или я вообще неправильно решил задачу." - напишите тест и проверьте.

Comment: решил, может, и правильно, но не оптимально. Если сумма номеров столбца и ряда четная (считать, что а = 1, b = 2 итд) - клетка черная, если нечетная - белая

Comment: @Igor - Большое спасибо. Были некоторые проблемы, и соответственно непонимание. По этому и выложил код для критики.

Comment: @Эникейщик, , большое спасибо! Буду использовать в будущем!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если брать сам код, то тут есть несколько проблем:

1. Если я захочу написать **заглавную** букву (A, B, ..., H), то Ваша программа поведёт себя неправильно; следует сперва уменьшить регистр вводимой буквы с помощью `lower()`;
2. 

```py
for letter_checking in letters_list:
        if letter==letter_checking:
                chess_desk_letter.append(letter)
                break
else:
        print('Not in list, use A-H')
```

Зачем использовать `for` с перебором ВСЕХ букв, когда можно просто проверить, не входит ли введённая буква в списке с помощью `in`?

```py
if letter in letters_list:
    ....
```

3. Непонятно, зачем валидные букву/цифру сохранять в отдельные переменные-списки, когда их можно просто оставить в изначальных. Отсюда следует
4. Почему бы не связать проверки через `if/elif/else`, чтобы после проверки всех условий было ясно, что код работает с валидными значениями?

Наконец, алгоритм можно довольно сильно упростить: если у нас есть списки букв и цифр, а также введённые строки, то мы можем с помощью функции [`index()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) найти местонахождение цифры и буквы в списках, а затем сравнить эти индексы по модулю 2. Если модули будут совпадать, то клетка чёрная, иначе — белая.

Исходя из вышенаписанного, вот пример кода:

```py
letter = input('Please enter the letter-> ').lower()
digit = int(input('Please enter the digit-> '))

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
digits = range(1, 9)

if letter not in letters:
    print('Not in list, use A-H')
elif digit not in digits:
    print('Not in list, use 1-8')
else:
    letter_index = letters.index(letter)
    digit_index = digits.index(digit)
    if letter_index % 2 == digit_index % 2:
        print('Black')
    else:
        print('White')
```

Comment: Спасибо, за развернутый ответ! Про index,вообще не знал. Видимо еще не дошел до него =) Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 3):

Простое выражение, перед этим нужно проверить диапазон цифр и букв. digit = 0..7 (можно 1..8 и просто инвертировать результат).  И не забудьте сделать letter lowercase, если нужно:

```
(ord(letter) + digit)%2
```

1 = черный
0 = белый

Comment: ну и проверку letter от 'a' (97) до 'h' (104)

Comment: Вот зачем писать непонятное число `97`, если можно написать понятное выражение, откуда оно взялось `ord('a')`?

Comment: Проще надо быть, проще: `is_white = (ord(letter) + digit) % 2`

Comment: @АрсенКул Спасибо!

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Вау, даже не знал что так можно,спасибо

Comment: @Oleksandr_I, можно и так `is_white = (ord(letter) ^ digit) & 1`

Comment: Спасибо @TigerTV.ru. Изменил ответ